# MS Access: Will Access 2016 application work with Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

If I create a VERY simple 2016 Access Database with [max] 5 simple Tables, a Data Entry Form, 3 or 4 Search Forms to display data and maybe a couple of Reports - will it work for a friend who is using Access 2007?

I *have* worked on converting complex Access DBs to newer versions - at Employer sites - but never sending a DB created in 2016 to someone using 2007.

I'm hoping that because what my friend described is a really simple application for his pretty simple business [manufacturing] needs, there won't be any problems.

He *did* also say he can buy Access 2016 if that is the easiest way to proceed.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you send him an .accdb, it *might* work, but my guess is No. If you send him an .accde, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ***try***.

If it works, OK; if not, you will have develop in Access 2007 or your friend will have to upgrade to Access 2016 or newer.

Comment: Thanks @gustav! My friend never moved on this so there was no reason for me to pursue.